# Adding HTML elements dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote a script that could dynamically add HTML elements but the problem here is there are values to these element which are also created dynamically, below is the scripts

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#noOfSegments").change(function(){
var counter=$("#noOfSegments").val();
for(i=1; i<=counter; i++){
var row = $("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td><input type='text' name='segmentName"+i+"'></input></td><td><select name='dataType"+i+"'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option></select></td><td><select name='dataType"+i+"'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option></select></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='mandatoryFlag"+i+"'></td></tr>");
$("#segmentTable").append(row);
}
var rowcount = $("#segmentTable tr").length;
while (rowcount > counter) {
$("#segmentTable tr:last-child").remove();
rowcount = $("#segmentTable tr").length;
  }
 });
});
```

where my $("#noOfSegments") is a select with option values 1,2 and 3.
When i select option 3 first it gives me "+i+" as 1,2 and 3, but when i select option 1 first and the option 2 it gives me 1, 1 for "+i+" and if i select option 1 and then option 3 it gives me 1,1,2
Can you guys please help me with this?

Comment: I don't think I'm seeing your problem: [JS Fiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MBUKw/).

Answer (score 0):

You should `$("#segmentTable tr").remove()` (all `<tr>` nodes) before adding the new ones.

[Here's an edited fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c4rnh/)

What's happening with your code is that you add X new  nodes at the end of the table and then start deleting X nodes from the end of the table, in essence deleting some of the nodes you just added. You should either delete nodes from the top of the table or delete all nodes before you add the new ones (line I did in my fiddle).

Comment: Please take a read of the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for formatting guidance.

Comment: But then if i select option 1 it shows me the elements and then for select option 2 it does not show anything

Comment: deleting nodes from the top of the table helped me